# How to create a thread that will start immediately (even though there are many threads ready)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, clr

I'm trying to build a load tester, by creating one thread that makes rapid async http requests, ignoring the server response, and another thread that samples the server every 500 ms by sending a request and measuring the response time. Pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Load: {0} requests/second", input[i]);
    var trd = LunchSamlper();
    var callsPerSecond = input[i];
    for (j = 0; j < callsPerSecond * BATCH_TIME; j++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            await SendRequestAsyncIgnoreResponse(address, payload);
        }));
        Thread.Sleep(1000 / callsPerSecond);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    tasks.Clear();
    trd.Abort();
}

private static async Task SendRequestAsyncIgnoreResponse(Uri url, string data)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.UploadStringAsync(url, data));
}

private static Thread LunchSamlper()
{
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        while (true)
        {
            sw.Restart();
            SendRequestAndProcessResponse();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time:{0}, Threads in process: {1}, Response Time: {2}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    });
    t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    t.Start();
    return t;
}
```

Ideally, the sampler thread would wake up every 500ms, make the request, and measure the response time. 
Practically, the thread wakes up every 10+ seconds, making the test irrelevant. I'm not familiar with the CLR internals too well, but I'm guessing whats happening is that the async **responses** get queued up fast, requiring more and more threads to handle them, thus pushing the sampler thread down the scheduler. 
What I would like to do (but don't know how), is to force the sampler thread to stay at the top of the queue, kind of cheating the round robin Microsoft states they use. I tried giving it 'Highest' priority, but it didn't help.

**EDIT:**
Please see the new code above, this is the actual code I have executed, and the output is below. All of your comments were right - the sampler is not affected by the rest of the threads (the server response was too long)

However, you can clearly see that the more load there is, the more threads are presented in the process. I believe this reinforces my claim that the more async tasks there are, more threads are needed from the thread pool to handle them **when the tasks are ready** (that is, when the async part had finished). When too many tasks are ready in the queue, the thread pool has no choice but to create more threads. If I'm wrong, please explain to me what's really going on behind the scene. 
Output:

```
Threads in process: 5

Load: 2 requests/second
Time :10:38:46.2552818, Threads in process: 19, Response     Time : 454
Time :10:38:47.1143283, Threads in process: 22, Response     Time : 357
Time :10:38:47.9765673, Threads in process: 22, Response     Time : 359
Time :10:38:48.8408045, Threads in process: 22, Response     Time : 360
.
. (same stats for 30 seconds)
.
Time :10:39:15.6071230, Threads in process: 23, Response     Time : 351
Load: 20 requests/second
Time :10:39:16.2120124, Threads in process: 23, Response     Time : 369
Time :10:39:17.0811746, Threads in process: 23, Response     Time : 365
Time :10:39:17.9329613, Threads in process: 24, Response     Time : 348
Time :10:39:18.7825313, Threads in process: 24, Response     Time : 346
Time :10:39:19.6345169, Threads in process: 24, Response     Time : 345
Time :10:39:20.4919706, Threads in process: 24, Response     Time : 354
.
.
.
.
Time :10:39:41.9171558, Threads in process: 26, Response     Time : 359
Time :10:39:42.7701623, Threads in process: 26, Response     Time : 351
Time :10:39:43.6266869, Threads in process: 26, Response     Time : 353
Time :10:39:44.4826907, Threads in process: 26, Response     Time : 352
Time :10:39:45.3433820, Threads in process: 26, Response     Time : 358
Load: 50 requests/second
Time :10:39:46.5745915, Threads in process: 26, Response     Time : 358
Time :10:39:47.9899573, Threads in process: 28, Response     Time : 912
Time :10:39:50.5339321, Threads in process: 30, Response     Time : 2039
Time :10:39:54.8185811, Threads in process: 28, Response     Time : 3780
Time :10:40:02.5677990, Threads in process: 28, Response     Time : 7244
Time :10:40:16.3460440, Threads in process: 30, Response     Time : 13273
```

Side note:

At first, I didn't use a sampling thread. The code looked kind of like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRequests; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await SendRequestIgnoreResponse(sw))
            .ContinueWith(p=> MeasureServerResponse(sw));
        Thread.Sleep(1000 / requestsPerSecond);
    }
```

But I realized the measured time was incorrect, because the stopwatch was also counting the time the task spent in queue when the response was ready. This is how I came up with the idea of the sampler thread, which makes it's calls synchronously. Any new ideas will be seriously considered!

Last note:

For what is worth, the server under the load is local, on the same machine that generates the load. The method behind the addressed url makes a call to external resource, which takes ~300 ms.

Comment: Are you sure that the sampler thread isn't waking up or is the issue that something inside MeasureServerResponse is blocking due to contention with shared resources that your request threads are tying up?  Sleep is unreliable for any sort of precise timing, but a 10 second delay for a nominal 0.5 second sleep is suspicious.

Comment: You can't do any serious profiling with Thread.Sleep(). It doesn't occupy the CPU.

Comment: Manually created threads have nothing to do with the thread pool. They are not limited in any way. If you assign high priority (why isn't that code shown here?) the thread *will* run regularly. How did you determine that it does not? Replace `MeasureServerResponse` by `Console.WriteLine("x")`.

Comment: Please see my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that when you IO is properly async *there is no <s>spoon</s> thread*.  You're creating new threads just to spend a minuscule amount of time *starting* an asynchronous operation, as well as consuming thread pool time handling results that you never use.

Just don't do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRequests; i++)
{
    SendRequestIgnoreResponse();
    Thread.Sleep(1000 / requestsPerSecond);
}
```

Also keep in mind that `Thread.Sleep` doesn't have a particularly high level of precision.  It has precision down to a few dozen milliseconds at best, and possibly even hundreds of milliseconds in a system under stress.

Comment: I know the there is no thread. I didn't say there is. BUT, when the tasks are ready, and there are LOTS of tasks ready every few seconds, they do require a thread to handle them. My guess is that one thread is not enough, so there are more and more threads created to handle the ready tasks.

Comment: @shay__ They are handled by the thread pool, not a single thread, unless they're being marshaled to one through a synchronization context, in which case, you should ensure that that isn't happening.

Comment: Can you explain then why does the sampler work well (wakes up after ~500 ms) under a low rate load, but not under high load? Under a low load, the program has 4 threads, while under high load there are 30. BTW, thanks for your answers, I appreciate it.

Comment: @shay__ The more threads running in the system the less time each can be given to do work; they'll be given a smaller time slice and have to wait longer between each of them.

Comment: @shay__ You clearly have multiple places in your code where you are entirely needlessly sheduling work for thread pool threads when you just shouldn't be.  That your thread pool is getting completely saturated and is failing to keep up in its workload as a result is therefore unsurprising.  Stop scheduling work in a thread pool thread without good reason.  (Hint: in the code you've shown you never have a good reason to explicitly schedule work in a thread pool thread.)